# How do I sync app installs across devices?

Tags: ios

I have two android devices signed in to the same icloud account and apple account. All the accounts are the same. Is there a way I can have one install all the apps that are on the other?

Comment: I'm struggling to see what iCloud has to do with Android app installation.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't sync apps using iCloud across Android devices.

The syncing of apps only occurs between Apple devices signed-in with the same Apple ID.

Comment: I thought Apple Id and Icloud were the same account? Either way they are signed in to ALL the same accounts.

Comment: iCloud is a synchronisation service for Apple devices. AppleID is the identity used to access it. None of this will have any effect on an Android device. As far as I'm aware, all you can do from Android is access the web components of iCloud [using an AppleID]. You cannot access the App Store or install apps to Android from it.